# Click one item on a row only

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to disabled the other buttons in a row, when I have selected at least one?

```
$('.bet-offer div.option').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

The result should be the user can click on any buttons in a row, but once clicked, the other items on that row should be disabled already. However, the user can still select buttons from the other items in other rows.

Here's the sample fiddle:    http://jsfiddle.net/1vuf1gm7/3/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

buttons are nothing but siblings of each other in parent div. you can use `.siblings()` to target other button and remove the class  selected from it.

also you should use `.toggleClass()` instead of add/remove with hasClass condition:

```
$('.bet-offer div.option').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings('.option').removeClass('selected')
  $(this).toggleClass('selected')
});
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ktk5odsa/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('.bet-offer div.option').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $('.bet-offer div.option.disabled').removeClass("disabled");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('.bet-offer div.option:not(.selected)').addClass("disabled");
    }
});
```

This will add a `disabled` class to all the non-selected options.

Comment: i still have to add css for disabled class right? thanks for this!

Comment: Yep, and if you want to prevent clicking a disabled class you could change the first line of that JS to this: `$('.bet-offer div.option:not(.disabled)').click(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

This will disable the other buttons in the same row while one button has the class `selected`:

```
$('.bet-offer div.option').click(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
            $(this).siblings().css('pointer-events', 'auto');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $(this).siblings().css('pointer-events', 'none');
        }
    });
```